How to make reorder by mean work in boxplot in r?
I have looked at a few other posts where this problem has occurred but can't seem to apply any of the suggestions to my case. Whenever I try reorder with the mean it does not work but works when reorder is used with the median. Here is an example where I tried reorder with mean:



values <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,2,3,4,5,6,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)
group <- c('t1','t1','t1','t1','t1','t1','t2','t2','t2','t2','t2','t2','t3','t3','t3','t3','t3','t3')

df<- data.frame(values,group)


boxplot(values~group, data=df)     ## two groups with same median


mean_values <- aggregate(df$values, by = list(df$group), FUN = mean)
medianvalues <- aggregate(df$values, by = list(df$group), FUN = median)

mean_values # groups have different means
medianvalues # two groups have same median


 new_order1 <- with(df, reorder(group, values, mean, na.rm=T))   # want lowest mean first


boxplot(values~new_order1, data=df)  # but nothing changes?




Your order is right when checking new_order1 right?

I don't think so. I would expect t2 to move up above t1 when done by new_order1. Boxplot looks same to me.

Nothing changes because the original ordering of the groups is the same after ordering them by the means.
